# How to set two variables as one

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables

I have this question, and i can't find any radical answer...

So, is there any possibility to set with jQuery two variables as one, smth like this:

```
    var $self = {
        car_img_stage: $('.car_img_stage'),
        vis_home: $('#vis_home')
    }
```

and use after like that:

```
    $self.animate({
        'margin-left': '-1200px'
    }, 600)
```

Thx for help.

Comment: What your asking for can't be done without copying over all of the methods from `$.fn` to your object and having it do some additional logic on each one of them to ensure the correct element is targeted when you use `$self.animate()`. just cache them in two separate variables, and when you want to affect both, use `one.add(theother).dosomething()`

Comment: ok but, can i set them in some kind of one array? like this:         `var car_img_stage = $('.car_img_stage'), vis_home = $('#vis_home');` and use after `var self = $[vis_home,car_img_stage];` ?

Comment: No, because jQuery objects can't be created from an array of jQuery objects. They would each have to be converted to just a dom element, for example, `var car_img_stage = $('.car_img_stage').get();`

Comment: ok, thx for explenation

Comment: ok, i find this: `var self = jQuery.makeArray(vis_home,car_img_stage);` and it's working perfect

Comment: Perhaps this would help? http://api.jquery.com/add/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a combined selector that should accomplish the same thing:

```
$self = $('.car_img_stage,#vis_home');
```

Comment: but can i to use one of them after some actions? thats why i'v set like bellow

Comment: I'm sorry, but your English is broken. I'm not clear on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to accomplish this -

[Multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

```
$self = $('.car_img_stage,#vis_home');
```

[jQuery add](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
//basic use
$self = $('.car_img_stage').add('#vis_home');
```

These are both animated the same way:

```
$self.animate({
    'margin-left': -1200
}, 600);
```

Add is also useful if you want to cache your selectors and use them individually later.

```
//cached selectors
$car_img = $('.car_img_stage');
$vis_home = $('#vis_home');
$self = $car_img.add($vis_home);

$car_img.animate({
    'color': 'red'
}, 600);

$vis_home.animate({
    'height': 200
}, 600);

$self.animate({
    'margin-left': -1200
}, 600);
```

You could also leave your selector how it is and loop through it. This way is NOT recommended, but will technically work.

```
var $self = {
    car_img_stage: $('.car_img_stage'),
    vis_home: $('#vis_home')
}

for (var each in $self){
    $self[each].animate({
        'margin-left': -1200
    }, 600);
}
```

This next note is not related to the original question, but is an important point to remember when dealing with animating multiple selectors.

Note that when animating multiple selectors, any callbacks attached will fire for EACH ITEM ANIMATED. This is relevant when say, fading out a list of links (instead of the wrapper containing them), or something like that. To avoid this problem, you can use [a promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/), like so:

```
$self = $('.car_img_stage,#vis_home');

$self.animate({
    'margin-left': -1200
}, 600, function(){
    //callback code here to happen for every animated element.
}).promise().done(function(){
    //callback code here, to happen once when ALL animations are complete.
});
```

You can leave off either or both of these callback functions:

Just a callback:

```
$self.animate({
    'margin-left': -1200
}, 600, function(){
    //callback code here to happen for every animated element.
});
```

Just a promise:

```
$self.animate({
    'margin-left': -1200
}, 600).promise().done(function(){
    //callback code here, to happen once when ALL animations are complete.
});
```

Comment: added a section relating to your question about having separate selectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var some_things = $('.car_img_stage, #vis_home');

some_things.animate({
    'margin-left': '-1200px'
}, 600)
```

Comment: Using `$` before the variables clearly distinguishes them as jQuery objects. This is not an uncommon practice, although I don't generally do it myself.

Comment: `self` shadows the global `window.self`, not a good name for a variable.

Answer (score 0):

As additional answer from me i have find some other solve, and it's work.

```
var car_img_stage = $('.car_img_stage'),
    vis_home = $('#vis_home');

var self = jQuery.makeArray(vis_home,car_img_stage);
```

and action

```
self.animate({
    // some animate action
}, 600);
```

Comment: as jbabey points out above, you really don't want to use "self" as your variable name here.

Comment: Removed my previous comments about it not working. Example of it working here - http://jsfiddle.net/kcN5p/1/